# Partial loss of sound

Tags: technical-issues, battlefield-4

After playing for a number of hours, I've lost partial sound. Most painfully, I've lost the warning sound when I'm in a vehicle and someone has locked onto me or fired heatseakers at me. I tried lowering my graphics setting and restarted my computer. Are there known fixes?

Answer (score 1):

There's an audio option panel that you can use to re-enable those sounds. Here's a link for the How-To. Here are the main points from the site below.

Your Speaker System (BF3) / Speaker Type (BF4) has 5 possible options…

- War Tapes
- TV
- Hi-Fi
- Home Cinema
- Headphones

> A high dynamic range means the loud sounds (e.g. nearby explosions)
>   will be loud, while the quiet sounds (e.g. wind blowing in the trees)
>   will be fairly quiet. A low dynamic range means the loud sounds
>   (nearby explosions) will be loud, and the quiet sounds (wind) will be
>   slightly less loud. Perceived volume is incredibly important for sound
>   localization, so choosing a low-dynamic range option (e.g. War Tapes)
>   will sound loud and impressive, but you will lose a lot of information
>   because all the sounds will be loud at the same time. This makes it
>   seem like a chopper is directly overhead when it is really about 150
>   meters out. You’ll definitely be able to hear it coming, but you won’t
>   have a clue where it actually is.

I would suggest you select a High Dynamic and reset the audio option for lock-ons and explosives.

[Battlefield 4 Audio](http://bfmedic.com/battlefield-audio-options/)